# Pierre-Gilles de Gennes and adhesives

Tags: solid-state-physics, specific-reference, adhesion

Among many other fields, Pierre-Gilles de Gennes is credited with greatly contributing to the science of adhesives. One of the model oft cited is the "viscoelastic trumpet", for example in this [obituary](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/00218460701638995?src=recsys). First it is not clear at all to me what are the key features of this model. I haven't managed to find pedestrian enough a source. Then, as exemplified by the very same obituary, this does not seem to be the only contribution of de Gennes to the field, but I haven't found a clear and precise exposition. If anyone knows of a good reference, or can write an answer going beyond rather vague explanations…

Comment: is this a school assignment question?

Comment: @jsotola no, just curious.

Comment: When I google "de Gennes and adhesives", the first hit is my question as I write this! I have disabled Google search history on my machine for the record. Amusing!

Comment: Even though de Gennes won a Physics Nobel, this question really isn't in the wheelhouse of physics.SE.  I'd suggest chemistry.SE, which has [a tag on adhesion](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adhesion), for example.

Comment: "Soft Matter" are the key words if you want to know about de Gennes' achievements. See for example [the birth of soft matter physics, the physics of the everyday](https://www.theguardian.com/science/occams-corner/2015/may/12/the-birth-of-soft-matter-physics-the-physics-of-the-everyday) or [what is soft matter](http://soft-matter.seas.harvard.edu/index.php/What_is_soft_matter)

Comment: Nobel lecture : https://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/physics/laureates/1991/gennes-lecture.pdf